# How to get Album art in lock screen while playing music?

Tags: music

I have curated huge set of songs with proper ID3 tags and added Album art manually to them using MP3Tag tool. While they appear in Album selection page, I don't see them in the lock screen while playing. Do I need to embed the Artist image to MP3 file and mark it as Artist image? [ID3v2 Embedded Image Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2_Embedded_Image_Extension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artist image setting shown in Nate's answer is >only< applicable when playing music in the Music & Videos player (i.e. Xbox Music). This setting gives permission to fetch an image of the currently playing >artist< from Xbox Music and display it on your lock screen. It does not look at the art embedded in the file for the purpose of the lock screen, and if there is no artist imagery available then it shows nothing.

So what you want would need to be done by an app. I don't know of one which does this, though.

Comment: Hmmm, then that is not possible for the regional artists in my playlist then. Let me try with an international artist. But the embedded images do show up in Album and Song selection pages

Answer (score 2):

Windows Phone does not show album art in the lock screen, it shows an image of the artist. This image is automatically added from the XBOX Cloud. You can manually set images and album art using the MPA Tool but either way it will not show the album art on the lock screen.

There may be an app out there which does this but you will have to play the music through that app instead of XBOX/Zune.

Answer (score 1):

Album art won't show in lockscreen, the option in settings to show artist when playing music will show you a picture of the artist if it is in the zune database. It doesn't work very well as sometimes I don't get the lockscreen picture coming up even with a popular artist. I can't see what phone you have but if you are WP8 try this

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/mpatool/a6056e5e-34bd-4098-9cd8-4ed5df611d97?signin=true

Comment: Ohh, I have this tool but it couldn't search per my needs. So it looks like it is always an online fetch, no way to force the player to display the images we put.

Answer (score 0):

In the lock screen settings page, there is a checkbox for "Show artist when playing music". You need to enable it, as I believe it's off by default.

As far as I know, if your ID3 tags and art show up correctly in the Music/Video hub, they should also work on the lock screen after enabling it.

### What it looks like on my phone

[image: lock screen settings showing show music on home screen]

Comment: Of course, I did select that option. But I only get the grey text of artist name scrolling across in the lockscreen. Would that be because, the album art I embedded are all low quality images (200 x 200 px)?

Comment: I suspect that is the case; try something with a larger size (i.e. bigger than your phones screen resolution) and I suspect it'll show up.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work. Tried even with 1024x768 px image. Doesn't show up. VLC shows it thoguh.

Comment: Wild, is the song available in the store? I've got music I ripped off CDs and stuff I bought in the store, and they all show up, but the stuff from CDs also happen to be available in the store.

Answer (score 0):

The default music app in windows phone shows artist image while your music is in sync with xbox music(provided xbox music is available in your country region), so if not available it shows a solid grey background while playing music. You can make your lockscreen appear while playing music by switching off "show artist when playing music" in lockscreen settings.

OR

You could use the Nokia MixRadio app,this is a cool app, which makes the artist image offline once you play a song while connected to internet. Make sure your artist name is single not Like "xxx ft yyy" just "xxx" .